# collapse class is working for one time

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am making my header of a page using bootstrap. The problem is that it displays and collapse one time then it does not work.

```
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#xsNavbar" aria-controls="bs-navbar" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/Main/home/order"></a>
</div>

<div class="collapse" id="xsNavbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Drinks</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">House Hold</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Beauty</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Baby Items</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: add a code snippet with javascript and css.

Comment: Should not it work with just Bootstrap Javascript??

Comment: It might work with just bootstrap but we have no idea what role javascript has in your html. For that we need to look at your js code.

Comment: What's your whole navigation structure ? On this kind of [fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/jXeGJ17UC5) it seems to work ( on XS view ! )

Comment: I have included only 2 java-script files which are jquery.js and then bootstrap.js that I downloaded from here http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Post the full html code (or at least something that would run in a snippet or jsfiddle), you likely messed up on a parent container

Comment: Its my first time using jsfiddle so its not the way i wanted but code is there.
add bootstrap.js in it and i guess it will look like how i wanted then check my code why its only collapsing one time!!
https://jsfiddle.net/0843u7ge/

Comment: The code in the fiddle is very different from the original code you gave, which is the right code? Also, the code you posted works on collapse. Not sure what you thin is wrong?

Comment: Thanks a lot guys.
I was missing my bootstrap javascript.
I had included bootstrap.min.js which i downloaded from twitter.bootstrap but I dont know was not working.
Then, I included this and it worked like butter on fry pan.
http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably missing a parent container.

Make sure your code is wrapped in a `div` with `class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top"`

Here's what I have (working), just from adding that parent `div`

http://jsfiddle.net/tvaeuxh4/

Comment: Thanks alot ur jsfiddle makes me realize my mistake. It was not that I was missing class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top".
and Can u please tell me what u included externally on jsfiddle.
Mine jsfiddle is not looking like urs
https://jsfiddle.net/0843u7ge/3/
check it and tell me what to do because jsfiddle is good tool to share ur HTML,CSS,JS code online to show others. I might need it in future....

Comment: I included JQuery, the latest version of Bootstrap 3 (both the .js and .css). In the future, you can click the 'external' resources tab and it will show you too :)